# How to combine one-to-many relationship and many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My requirement is:  A post is created by a user (Author), many users can be tagged in a post (TaggedUsers). A user can create many post (CreatedPosts) and a user can be tagged in many posts (TaggedPosts). So I create 2 class of entities Post and User as below.

```
public class Post
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Title {get; set;}
  public string Body {get; set;}
  public User Author {get; set;}
  public ICollection<User> TaggedUsers {get; set;}
}
public class User
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Username {get; set;}
  public ICollection<Post> CreatedPosts {get; set;}
  public Collection<Post> TaggedPosts {get; set;}
}
```

So how can I configure relationship (using Fluent API or Data Annotation) in Code-first approach.
The database should have 3 tables: Users, Posts, PostTags.

Users:

- Id
- Username

Posts:

- Id
- User_id
- Title
- Body

PostTags:

- Id
- Post_id
- User_id

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Here is the documentation on relationships. https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Comment: @zAnthony in my case it is not just only many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you're trying to do:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
      : base(options)
  {
  }

public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Tags)
        .WithMany(p => p.Posts)
        .UsingEntity<PostTag>(
            j => j
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
                .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId),
            j => j
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
                .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId),
            j =>
            {
                j.Property(pt => pt.PublicationDate).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
                j.HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });
            });
}
```

}

```
 public class Post
 {
  public int PostId { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
  public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class Tag
{
   public string TagId { get; set; }

   public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
   public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
```

}

```
 public class PostTag
 {
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }

    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I will replace Tag entity in your code with my User. So I have to create third entity PostTag.

Comment: in your example, it does not include my important Author field which is a user object.